# Application not shown the dialog for permission of publish_action from facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code...

I used the logInWithPublishPermissions for login...

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    java.util.List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
//  LoginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
            FacebookShareActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            sharePhotoToFacebook();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
```

**sharePhotoToFacebook**

```
private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){


    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .setCaption("Caption")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)

            .build();
    ShareApi.share(content,shareCallback);

//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Snapshot shared On Facebook",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>(), REQUEST_CODE);



}
```

**But I want the app ask for permission it's not show the dialog of ask permission of publish.**

Comment: Are you trying with an app admin or at least someone with a role in the app? do you know about login review?

Comment: Yes @luschn sir, I am using this with own (admin) account it. but it is directly on the wall not asking permission of publish_action directly post

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for facebook login:

```
@Bind(R.id.login_button_fb)
 LoginButton login_button_fb;
.
.
.
.
 login_button_fb.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                        "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "public_actions"));
                login_button_fb.setFragment(LoginFragment.this);
                login_button_fb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        addToMainQueue(TCRequestGenerator.loginWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        showAlert(error.getMessage());
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    }
                });
```